# Find a recipient with a given address in a folder

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

My company needs an add-in for automatically adding offers to the email when it is the first time we send an email to a recipient.

My question is :

How can I check if this is the first time the user sends an email to the recipients?

I tried this but I receive error that Recipient is unknown property. And I also think that this is not the right approach...

```
        object folderItem;
        Boolean AlreadyEmailed = false;

        if (mail != null)
        {

            const string PR_SMTP_ADDRESS =
                "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E";
            Outlook.Recipients recips = mail.Recipients;
            foreach (Outlook.Recipient recip in recips)
            {
                Outlook.PropertyAccessor pa = recip.PropertyAccessor;
                string smtpAddress =
                    pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS).ToString();

                string filter = "[Recipient] = 'John@foo.com'";
                filter = filter.Replace("John@foo.com", smtpAddress);

                Debug.WriteLine(filter);

                folderItem = items.Restrict(filter);
                if(folderItem != null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("We found items that have the filter");
                    AlreadyEmailed = true;
                }

                //Debug.WriteLine(recip.Name + " SMTP=" + smtpAddress);
            }

            if(!AlreadyEmailed)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("This is the first time we email ... ");
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Sent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868242(v=office.15).aspx) property of the MailItem class returns a Boolean value that indicates if a message has been sent. In general, there are three different kinds of messages: sent, posted, and saved. Sent messages are items sent to a recipient or public folder. Posted messages are created in a public folder. Saved messages are created and saved without either sending or posting.

Also you may use the following Extended MAPI properties that deal with the message state (replied/forwarded):

- PR_ICON_INDEX (`http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10800003`)
- PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED (the DASL name is `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003`)
- PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTION_TIME (0x10820040)

To get these values use the [PropertyAccessor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb176395(office.12).aspx) class (see the corresponding properties of Outlook items).

Be aware, new Outlook items don't have the `EntryID` property set.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `To`/`CC`/`BCC` properties in `Items.Find/Restrict`. Note that it is better to use `Find` in your case since you only need a single match, not all of them. Also note that `Restrict` will not return null if no matches are found, but rather an Items collection with `Items.Count == 0`.

That being said, `To`/`CC`/`BCC` might not include addresses, only names, so search won't help you. You can still loop through all items in the folder and explicitly check the `Recipients` collection of each item, but that will be hugely inefficient.

On the Extended MAPI level (C++ or Delphi), one can create subrestrictions on message recipients (or attachments), but the Outlook Object Model does not expose that functionality.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author), its implementation of [Find/Restrict](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOItems.htm) does support queries on the `Recipients` collection:

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set YourOutlookFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
set rFolder = Session.GetFolderFromID(YourOutlookFolder.EntryID)
set rItems = rFolder.Items
set rMsg = rItems.Find("Recipients LIKE 'John@foo.com' ")
while not (rMsg Is Nothing)
  Debug.print rMsg.Subject
  set rMsg = rItems.FindNext
wend
```

In C# (not tested):

```
Redemption.RDOSession Session = new Redemption.RDOSession();
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT;
set rFolder = Session.GetFolderFromID(YourOutlookFolder.EntryID);
Redemption.RDOMail rMsg = rFolder.Items.Find("Recipients LIKE 'John@foo.com' ") ;
AlreadyEmailed = rMsg != null;
```